# How to sample from the joint distribution of two random variables of which I only know the marginal distributions and their correlation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, copula

In brief, my question is: How can I sample from the joint distribution of two random variables of which I only know their marginal distributions and their correlation, but not their joint distribution?

To illustrate, let $f_\epsilon$ and $g_\phi$ be the densities of errors in a seemingly unrelated regression model with two equations
$$y_1= a_1 + b_1 x + \epsilon \\
  y_2= a_2 + b_2 x + \phi $$

Is there any way to sample from the joint distribution of $\epsilon, \phi$ in a way that $\epsilon$ and $\phi$ are correlated?

For example, when $f_\epsilon, g_\phi$ are both normal, the multivariate normal distribution has a covariance parameter for this, and I can sample the multivariate normal distribution easily. However, is there a way to draw from the joint distribution if, for example, $f_\epsilon$ is normal, but $g_\phi$ is logistic- or t-distributed?

Possibly copulas have to be used that I am not so familiar with.

Comment: A joint distribution is not uniquely defined by marginals and correlation. Except with additional assumptions such as, e.g., the joint is Normal.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks I will check this (I do not understand how your two comments can apply at the same time unless the paper makes some additional assumptions?)

Comment: It is possible to simulate from a joint distribution such that (i) the marginals are $f$ and $g$, (ii) the correlation is $\varrho$, but this imposes choosing the joint as there is no unicity. It is therefore risky in that the outcome of the simulation may vary according to this choice. See for instance the many families of copulas, all designed for this purpose. (I removed the link to the paper as it makes strong assumptions on the correlation and anyway ends up choosing one particular joint distribution among the infinite range of compatible joints!)